# System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded while updating through Data loader

Tags: trigger

Can any one help me out with this error

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:CMAccountAssignmentTrigger:
>   System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

While updating industry field through Dataloader.

Trigger

```
trigger CMAccountAssignmentTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

  // Assignment is already in progress - this trigger is probably being raised by the assignment engine itself
  if(CMScoring.AssignmentInProgress()) return;

    // Check for assignment
    Boolean startassignment = false;
    for(Account act:Trigger.New)
    {
      //System.Debug('Account assignment field is ' + act.Trigger_Assignment_Workflow__c);
        if(act.Trigger_Assignment_Workflow__c) startassignment = true; // Trigger assignment if set
    }
    if(startassignment) CMScoring.StartAssignment();
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing much can be said as to why you're getting this error by looking at the trigger code. You should share the `CMSScoring` class as that will have the actual logic and that is needed to help you out..

Comment: There must be lot of things going in trigger and called classes. Try to debug and optimize the code.

Comment: for the starters, you can reduce the batch size in dataloader. This option is in the settings.

Comment: @Mugambo,@Ashwani,@Mr.Frodo,@
Marc Zaharescu :Thanks for your response.The apex class is more than 900+lines ,their are few lines been commented may be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this error is that when using the data loader for inserting/updating records, salesforce compiler performs the action in bulk. (it inserts/updates the dataset by 200 records at time).

Everything being processed in the cloud there are a couple of limits you'd want to be aware of such as no more than 101 SOQL statemnts, 150 DML statements or around 10 seconds compilation time for an event. The latter one is the one that seems to cause you problems.

You could wither try to use the data loader with less than 200 records at a time, I'd try for 150 , 100 , 50. (quick fix)

Or you could try to look at your apex class and try to optimize your code. You can do this by filtering your queries, or using `Map` instead of `List` when storing records and going through them etc.